# Error: Variable uses an Automation Type not supported in VBScript

Tags: c++, vbscript

I am executing a VBScript function in C++ using  Microsoft script control (*`IScriptControlPtr` interface*).

VBScript Function:

```vb
Function Add1(a,b)
   Add1 = a+b
End Function
```

I need to pass unsigned long values to the parameters `a` and `b`.

So I assigned parameters datatype as `VT_UI4`. But When executing the function I am getting the error "Variable uses an Automation Type not supported in VBScript".

To my requirement , how to handle unsigned long values?

Comment: As long as you don't try to do maths with them they are as you set them. It is how the integer is interpreted that matters. So `A = &hffffffff`. It is -1 if you try and use it in VBScript. But it holds it's value if you don't try to use it as a number. If passing to a function just pass it. VBScript will think you are passing -1 and the function will gets the bits that an unsigned integer of 2^30 has.

Answer (score 4):

VBScript only supports signed 2- and 4-byte Integers. So you have to change your arguments to `VT_I4`, or use type conversion functions like `UnsignedToLong` and `LongToUnsigned`. See below for the additional information.

- [How To Convert Between Signed and Unsigned Numbers](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/189323)
- [VBScript Data Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9e7a57cf(v=vs.84).aspx)

Comment: True, but could you at least refer to it in relation to VBScript not Visual Basic for Applications, they are not mutually exclusive. In this case the information is correct but here is the [VBScript documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9e7a57cf(v=vs.84).aspx) for reference.